# What common and/or traditional Turkish dishes are vegan?

Tags: veganism, food, travel

Are there any common and/or traditional Turkish dishes which are vegan?

Comment: Here's a good list to get started!
https://foxnomad.com/2015/04/30/12-turkish-dishes-that-are-unintentionally-vegan/

Answer (score 6):

There's a dish called Yelanchi, which is stuffed grape leaves. I was told Yelanchi comes from Turkish word meaning liar, since ordinarily the (dolma) stuffing would contain meat. However, this variation is vegetarian/vegan and includes rice, herbs and even walnuts in some recipes.

[Here](http://www.mission-food.com/2010/12/yalanchi-vegetarian-stuffed-grape.html) is a link to a recipe.